# ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 on Azure DevOps

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am having trouble while building iOS App in Azure DevOps. I am getting below error while running xcode build task

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

I am using xcode version 13, MacOs latest agent in Azure DevOps.

I am following below steps

pod install,
xcode build

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve above error?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but no error is shown for me. just return code: 65

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? If yes, pls share

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines below to your Podfile to specify that you do not need to sign the Pods;

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
 end
```

Comment: @oyenigum this does not help in my case, do you have any other solutions?